# OAuth2 Python API client best pratice on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api-python-client, google-oauth

I'm using the two-legged OAuth2 flow provided by `AppAssertionCredentials` Class on GAE env.

```
...
credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope=API_AUTH_SCOPES)
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http(memcache))
drive_service = build("drive", "v2", http=http)
...
```

The above code was placed on the beginning of my Python app class. It works fine for now... But I observed that for every http request my app tries to refresh the OAuth2 token.

My question is: Is that ok? Should I care about token expiration/validation or OAuth2 API usage limits? Shoud I store the credential in a Storage mechanism and reuse it for next requests?

The `AppAssertionCredentials` [class docs](http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.appengine.AppAssertionCredentials-class.html) says

> This credential does not require a flow to instantiate because it represents
>   a two legged flow, and therefore has all of the required information to
>   generate and refresh its own access tokens.

The `_refresh(self, http_request)` doc says

> Since the underlying App Engine app_identity implementation does its
>   own caching we can skip all the storage hoops and just to a refresh
>   using the

I'm confused about the correct usage of Service Accounts OAuth flow on GAE.

I appreciate any recommendation on this topic.

**Update:**
the statement: "*I observed that for every http request my app tries to refresh the OAuth2 token.*"
is not true when using `AppAssertionCredentials` on GAE! Observing the logs carefully I see the `token refresh` executes only once. It appears GAE takes care of the OAuth2 handshake behind the scenes when using `AppAssertionCredentials` on GAE.